# Mysql Storing multi values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, list

I have a tables called userAccounts userProfiles and usersearches.

Each userAccount may have multiply Profiles. Each user may have many searches.
I have the db set up working with this. However in each search there may be several user profiles.

Ie, each user account may have a profile for each member of their family. 
They then want to search and include all or some of their family members in their search. The way i would kinda like it to work is have a column in user searches called profiles and basically have a list of profileID that are included in that search. (But as far as i know, you can't do this in sql)

The only way i can think i can do this is have 10 columns called profile1, profile2 ... profile10 and place each profileid into the column and 0 or null in the unused space. (but this is clearly messy )

Comment: Storing multiple values in one column isn't the best idea. But to create multiple columns is probably the worst one. What you need is one more table to relate searches and profiles with columns `search_id, profile_id`.

Comment: yeah, i figured it was a bad idea, just didnt know what else,

ie  table searchlookup 
searchid, profileID
1,123
1.234
1,456
2,123

ect ?

Comment: In other words - you need a many-to-many relation - i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Creating columns of the form *name1*...*nameN* is a clear violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Arbitrarily having ten of them is not the right approach, that's an assumption that will prove to be either wildly generous or too constrained most of the time. Since you're using a relational database, try and store your data relationally.

Consider the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  UNIQUE KEY index_on_name (name)
);

CREATE TABLE profiles (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  email VARCHAR(255),
  KEY index_on_user_id (user_id)
);
```

With that you can create zero or more profile records as required. You can also add or remove fields from the profile records without impacting the main user records.

If you ever want to search for all profiles associated with a user:

```
SELECT ... FROM profiles
  LEFT JOIN users ON
    users.id=profiles.user_id
  WHERE users.name=?
```

Using a simple `JOIN` or subquery you can easily exercise this relationship.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that the approach violation  Zero, One or Infinity Rule of database normalization.  however, and what you have posted is what i have set up.  My issue is how to add multi profiles to each search.

Comment: I added an example query at the end. If you'd set it up this way you would've saved me a lot of time by posting **your schema**.

Comment: @Strawberry Don't blame me, I'm just here trying to help.

Comment: I know you're just trying to help. You've proabably helped thousands of people here. It's still your fault though !

Comment: @Strawberry That is a very odd phrasing, then.